# Pyflink example from official docs end in a segfault

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I'm running pyflink 1.17.1 on a macbook pro with m1 chipset, with python version 3.10.0 and java version 11.

I run both table and datastream examples, both examples seem to run to the end and then segfault:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/python/datastream_tutorial/
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/python/table_api_tutorial/

datastream example output:

```
(returns,--puzzles,1)
[1]    33861 segmentation fault  python-datastream.py
```

table example output:

```
...
+I[remember'd., 1]
[1]    34246 segmentation fault  python flink-table.py
```

I've tried changing python versions, not working.